# Why are Angular Keystrokes not run synchronously? Or how can I make them run synchronously?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I make Angular 4/2 keystroke events run synchronously?
When I run this code the keys are not always run in order of firing.

Template

```
<div
  contenteditable="true"
  (keydown)="divKeyDown($event)"
  (keyup)="divKeyUp($event)">
</div>
```

Component

```
divKeyDown(event) {
  console.log('Keydown');
  // OFTEN GETS FIRED BEFORE KEYUP OF PREVIOUS STROKE
}
divKeyUp(event) {
  console.log('Keyup');
}
```

Comment: Do you need Something like this Plnkr? https://plnkr.co/edit/GYWY2HxFz41tmiXswFNs?p=preview (Press the Ctrl key), check that I'm using @HostListener.

Comment: @JancoBoscan I am seeing the same issue as the OP posted (https://plnkr.co/edit/xN38ZlziYdqYI8qJsDDZ?p=preview). JustinLevine I assume this functionality happens because keyup & keydown are separate event streams. So I don't know if there is anything to really do about it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @LLai I believe it is because EventEmitter is used in the background, but there is a toggle of isAsync in its constructor.  I'm wondering if its possible to inform it that it is not async.  In my contenteditable, I take control over the input on the keydown, and then reset the caret position on the keyup event.   If they don't fire synchronously, then it gets screwed up when the keyboard events are fired quickly.

Comment: @JustinLevine Looking at the angular source files, isAsync is synchronous by default. There might be an alternative way. What do you need from the keydown event to reset the caret position in the keyup event?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you really want to do, but, may be the function needed may be done when the input gain focus ?

Comment: I'm trying to run everything in one event such as the keydown event, but somehow, setting the selection behaves differently in the keydown event than it does in the keyup event even if I have prevented the default behavior.  If I have to I'll just override these processes with vanilla if I have to.  It just doesn't make sense to me why Angular would set up keystrokes to be handled this way.

Comment: I've realized that by trying to set the caret within the 'keydown' event, it will only be reset when Angular rerenders the view due to the change in state.  I guess I cannot rely on 'keyup' as an event that will be fired after 'keydown' synchronously, which makes sense in a way if you were to see if other keys were pressed while others were still down, but isn't helpful in my case.What I ended up doing is using the 'ngAfterViewChecked' lifecycle hook to reset the caret as it is always 100% fired after the view has been rerendered and before another keystroke event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Keyup is only fired when the key has literally become up and has no concern of other keystrokes.
- Keypress would be a better event to use in this scenario as it is always fired directly after keydown, and never before another keystroke.
- This is default behavior and not related directly to Angular.

Even in vanilla JS, the same behavior is observed:

```
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    console.log('keydown'); // FIRED ONCE
});
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('keypress', event => {
    console.log('keypress'); // FIRED AFTER KEYDOWN
});
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    console.log('keyup'); // FIRED WHEN THE KEY HAS LITERALLY BEEN RELEASED
});
```

(In this scenario I have used Angular's 'ngAfterViewChecked' lifecycle hook to handle the changes in state directly after the 'keydown' event has completed)